# Prepared Statement Failing (With an Error Message!)

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am getting this error when trying to insert data into a data table

```
Error Saving data. [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]COUNT field incorrect
```

I looked at the appropriate data table and there does not exist a field called COUNT either hidden or not hidden. Is this some SQL terminology that I should be familiar with?

*An Extension of this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197110/prepared-statement-failing)*

Comment: Please post your code, especially the query you are using for the prepared statement.

Comment: You like have SQL syntax that Jet doesn't support. Post the SQL or nobody is going to be able to help you.

Comment: passing null values into the prepared statement is what caused the problem, I just have to wait another 6 hours before I can accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that passing null values into the prepared statement also causes this errror.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic error message which is *usually* caused by incorrect statement syntax (like missing quote somewhere). Double check your SQL and post it here along with parameters / table schema if you need further help.